# how to get directory list upto level 2 in directory

Tags: php, directory

How to get files and directory list from a folder upto level 2? Here level is dynamic.

For ex:

```
1
  1.1
  1.2
  1.3
2
  2.1
  2.2
3
  3.1
4
  4.1
  4.2
```

1,2,3,4 - is folders and 1.1, 1.2,1.3 ..etc may be folder / files. 
1.1, 1.2 may have sub-folders but as per max level condition, it should not stopped traversing more than second level.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"While loop" is continuously loop until the statement is false.

```
while (readdir)
    if(folder)
        while(readir)
            if(file)
                echo filename
    else
        echo filename
```

PHP Example (Linux):

```
class start_class {

    var $limit = 3;
    var $lvl = false;

    function open_directory($dir){
        if(!$this->lvl){
            $this->limit = $this->limit + substr_count($dir,'/');
            $this->lvl = true;
        }

        $handle = opendir($dir);

        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

            if(!preg_match('[^(\.)]',$entry)){
                if(@opendir( ($sub = $dir.'/'.$entry) ) !== false){
                    if($this->limit > substr_count($dir,'/')){
                        echo $sub;
                        echo '<br>';
                        $this->open_directory($sub);
                    }
                }else{
                    echo $dir.'/'.$entry;
                    echo '<br>';
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

$class = new start_class();
$class->limit = 2;
$class->open_directory('/var/www');
```